# How does http caching work in combination with the accept-language header

Tags: http, caching

I am trying to understand the deeper inner workings of the caching that happens in the browser. Could you help me?

The page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching states this: "The primary cache key consists of the request method and target URI (often, only the URI is used because only GET requests are caching targets)."

Do i understand it correctly when i state / recall it like this?:

The response coming from a GET request to `http://my.site/my/resource` is stored in a key value pair like database where the key will either be `GET http://my.site/my/resource` or `http://my.site/my/resource`. I think of the response as the HTML / JSON, whathever the response body will contain.

I suspect that this interpretation is flawed in some ways:

What if i do a GET request to the url `http://my.site/my/resource` with an `accept-language: nl-NL` header. And immediately after that i do another GET request with `accept-language: en-US`. I assume because of what started to understand earlier, the second request should return the same response as from the first request. Because the cache keys are the same. Do i understand that correctly?

If that is correct, how can a request result in a different representation then when the accept-language header is changed. Do you need to send a header with the request, to bypass the cache when the accept-language header was changed?

Comment: See the [`Vary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary) header.